# Get files from specifically structured sub-folders?

Tags: c#

How do I get `*.xml` files from a specifically structured folder/sub-folder system in array to perform some operation.

Eg: The sample structure of the parent folders in user provided path (say, **myPath**) is

```
2017-36459-20124-301236\2017\36459\20124\301236\301236.xml
```

I cannot use things like `string[] tarDir = Directory.GetDirectories(myPath, "foldernameinitial");` as the folder name is changeable.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can simply use _Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)_

Comment: @Steve What if some other sub-folder contains xml files also and I only want the xml files inside the desired folder ,e,x. folder 301236 in the above example

Comment: @Bumba Then you choose the next higher parent folder. Or you choose the root folder and filter those files out that you dont need.

Comment: How can I tell the program the structure of the folders somthing like `var xmlFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDirectory, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(f) f Like "*\#*\#*\#*.xml").ToArray`

Comment: So as far as I understand, you want to get only `.xml` files from the last sub-folder which only contains files **and no sub directory**. am I right?

Comment: @o_O for starter, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I gathered clarification from your comments, this will get you all the sub-directories with only files in them ie., the last sub-directory

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetLastDirectory(string path) =>
     Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       .Where(dir => Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Length == 0);
```

Now use it as:

```
var MyDirectories = GetLastDirectory(@"D:\Softwares\Xtras"); //your path goes here
foreach (var subdir in MyDirectories)
{
   var onlyXMLfiles = Directory.GetFiles(subdir, "*.xml");
   foreach (var file in onlyXMLfiles)
   {
      //do your operation
   }
}
```

---

To be frank I don't know regex, I tried this pattern match at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ojEtzA/1). But as you said in the comments below you want to match the pattern of directory structure also, you can do this:

```
string pattern = @"\d{4}-\d{4,10}-\d{4,10}-\d{4,10}\\\d{4}\\\d{4,10}\\\d{4,10}\\\d{4,10}";

//Now you won't have to use "GetLastDirectory", instead use "Directory.GetDirectories"
var MyDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories("your path goes here");
foreach (var subdir in MyDirectories)
{
    if ((Regex.Match(subdir, pattern) != Match.Empty))
    {
       var onlyXMLfiles = Directory.GetFiles(subdir, "*.xml");
       foreach (var file in onlyXMLfiles)
       {
           //do your operations
       }
    }         
}
```

Probable pattern explanation:

```
\        :   match keyword, maybe!?<br>
-        :   hyphen as mentioned in the folder structure<br>
\d       :   match digits only<br>
\d{4}    :   match digits of length 4 and above<br>
\d{4,10} :   match digits of length 4 and limit upto upto 10<br>
\\       :   match \ as in the folder path<br>
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there a better approach to it though? What if I want to get the xml file from a sub-folder which is not the last sub-folder in the structure?

Comment: Then you can simply use `var onlyXMLfiles = Directory.GetFiles(yourpath, "*.xml");` Just remember to put only the directory structure, and don't include filename in it. Eg: `@"D:\Softwares\Xtras"`

Comment: But how do I describe the directory structure to the program? The name of the each sub-directory(also parent directory) can be different for different parent directories. Suppose I'm giving the path `D:\Software\Xtras` to the program and inside the `Xtras` directory are my directories like `2017-36459-20124-301236,  2016-16459-21324-501206, ...etc` and these directories have the structure described in the question and suppose the files that I want to get are in the 2nd sub-folder of the parent folders `2017-36459-20124-301236` i.e. folder name `36459`?

Comment: okay, If I take `2017-36459-20124-301236\2017\36459\20124\301236` , here `2017-36459-20124-301236` will always have character length as : `4-5-5-6`, and will be differentiated with a `-`; then these number blocks are created as sub-directories, where the last sub-directory's name is taken to save a `.xml` file

Comment: Well, the character length may vary and there could also be another folder in the 2nd slot i.e. folder `2017` in the above mentioned structure and that folder may contain xml files is well which I might want to get to another array, do you get it now?

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if you can make something out of it

Answer (score 0):

```
 var job_folders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(textBox1.Text, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            if (job_folders.ToArray().Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO job folders are found...");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string job_folder in job_folders)
                {
                    var target_xml_file = Directory.GetFiles(job_folder, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(x)).ToLower() == "xml");
                    var target_meta_file = Directory.GetFiles(job_folder, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(x)).ToLower() == "meta");

                }
            }
```